# Want to have that .scroll animation, even when the datasource is not set in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have got a `UIPageViewController` that displays five `ViewControllers` (contained in an array of `ViewControllers`). I am using gesture recognisers to move the page in backward/forward direction, instead of the `viewControllerBefore`/`viewControllerAfter` methods. It is working fine, but the pages change suddenly. I want to have the animation similar to that when I used to get with `.scroll` applied. 
I want to be able to display two `ViewControllers`, similar to what we experience when we slide slowly in `.scroll` animation.
Can you suggest how to do that?
Thanks.

I was facing issues with scrolling, as I mentioned in this question -> [[Disable swiping in horizontal UICollectionView inside my PageViewController to swipe in UIPageViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57766210/disable-swiping-in-horizontal-uicollectionview-inside-my-pageviewcontroller-to-s])
So, I decided to comment this line -> self.dataSource = self
And I decided to provide gesture-related functionality explicitly.

```
@objc func handleSwipe(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    print(gesture.direction)
    switch gesture.direction {
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.down:
        print("down swipe")
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.up:
        print("up swipe")
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.left:

        self.setViewControllers([ViewControllerArray[1]], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)

    case UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.right:

        self.setViewControllers([ViewControllerArray[2]], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)

    default:
        print("other swipe")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `animated: false`?

Comment: @Erumaru omg! such a silly mistake from my side! Thanks a ton for pointing this out for me :)

Comment: I'm glad to know that helps, I've added answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `animated` parameter to `true`

```
@objc func handleSwipe(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    print(gesture.direction)
    switch gesture.direction {
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.down:
        print("down swipe")
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.up:
        print("up swipe")
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.left:

        self.setViewControllers([ViewControllerArray[1]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

    case UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.right:

        self.setViewControllers([ViewControllerArray[2]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

    default:
        print("other swipe")
    }
}
```